# How to exclude association belongs-to-many from an instance in sequelize?

Tags: database, orm, relational-database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to exclude a junction model from a query with the association of a model, this is how they are associated:

```
Warehouse.associate = function(models) {
  Warehouse.Products = Warehouse.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
    as: {
      singular: 'product',
      plural: 'products',
    },
    through: models.WarehouseProducts,
    foreignKey: "warehouse_id",
    otherKey: "product_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
  });
}

Product.associate = function(models) {
  Product.Warehouses = Product.belongsToMany(models.Warehouse, {
    as: {
      singular: "warehouse",
      plural: "warehouses"
    },
    through: models.WarehouseProducts,
    foreignKey: "product_id",
    otherKey: "warehouse_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
  });
}
```

And this is the code that I use to retrieve the product of a warehouse:

```
export const prefetchWarehouse =  [
  validator.params.warehouse,
  async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      if (validator.errors(req)) {
        throw validator.stack;
      } else {
        req.warehouse = await Warehouse.findById(req.params.warehouse);
        next();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  }
];

export const getProduct = [
  validator.params.product,
  async function(req, res, next) {
    const result = await req.warehouse.getProducts({
      where: {
        id: {
          [Op.eq]: req.params.product
        }
      },
      plain: true
    });
    console.log('===>', result);
  }
]
```

And this is the output:

[image]
Is there anyway to avoid not getting back that association?

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran across this behavior, and i solved it by just setting `joinTableAttributes` to an empty array like so `joinTableAttributes: []`.

```
export const getProduct = [
  validator.params.product,
  async function(req, res, next) {
    const result = await req.warehouse.getProducts({
      joinTableAttributes: [], // Here
      where: {
        id: {
          [Op.eq]: req.params.product
        }
      },
      plain: true
    });
    console.log('===>', result);
  }
]
```

hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you Mohdule, actually this is what I was looking for, and it solves my issue in the same way :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using the junction model in my handler to avoid it:

```
export function WarehouseProducts(WarehouseProducts) {
  WarehouseProducts.associate = function(models) {
    WarehouseProducts.Products = WarehouseProducts.belongsTo(models.Product, {
      as: "product"
    });
  };
}
```

And then in the handler:

```
const result = await WarehouseProducts.findOne({
  where: {
    warehouse_id: { [Op.eq]: req.params.warehouse },
    product_id: { [Op.eq]: req.params.product }
  },
  include: [ "product" ]
});

res.json(result.product);
```

Although, it would be nice to doing in the way that I was looking for because the same function "prefetchWarehouse" is reused in others endpoints, so that would help to avoid. Even though the code looks more optimized, but anyway, if someone else has any suggestion I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Another way to solve this and in a beauty way is using raw queries from sequelize, that's how I did and now my queries are really clean/safe and really good.