# Sequelize: always get association/relation

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to always get associated model (relation) while querying parent model?

For example:

```
    Foo.init {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      bar_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }...

    Bar.init {
       name: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }...

   Bar.hasOne(Foo, {
      as: 'coolname',
      foreignKey: 'bar_id'
   })
```

Is it possible to always get foo inside Bar when I do `Bar.findAll()`? Without 'include'

Because Bar is also a child of `Zoo` (Zoo has many Bar) and when I do:

```
Zoo.findByPk(1, {
  include: Bar
  // somehow I need to include Foo in all Bars
})
```

I need to get Zoo with all it's Bars and each Bar should have it Foo.

I found Nested Eager Loading, but interested maybe there is a way right inside model definition?

Like in python's SqlAlchemy: there is a way to always join relation without additional querying

Comment: Try this solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567770/how-to-exclude-association-belongs-to-many-from-an-instance-in-sequelize Let me know if it works. (-:

Comment: @thegreytangent pleas check my answer, defaultScope do the trick, works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defaultScope of Model do the trick.

I just added:

```
  defaultScope: {
    include: 'foocoolname'
  }
```

where I define options of my Model (part, when we give sequalize instance, tablename, etc) and now every Bar has it field without additional conditions at querying.

And it's not only power of scope, we can do many interesting things with it. Sequelize is very powerful tool.

More info about scopes here - https://sequelize.org/v7/manual/scopes.html